# Qt: Custom size of background image

Tags: c++, qt, background, scale

I would like to change the size of my background image so that it doesn't claim the full size of my label.
e.g. in this case

[image]

the sun symbol is supposed to be shorter in length so it doesn't look that long and doesn't affect the text below. I placed the background with the setStyleSheet function and the text with the setText function. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What about `QLabel::setScaledContents(false)`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: What about two labels (aligned e.g. with a `QVBoxLayout`) where one shows the image and one the text? FYI: [QLabel::setPixmap()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) and (maybe) [QPixmap::fromImage()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage). (You could pick the color of image from the bottom to set the appropriate background color for the text label. With this, it's probably hard to see the "fake".) ;-)

Comment: Just FYI: [SO: Qt - How to create Image that scale with window, and keeps aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852010/7478597)